# How to find duplicates of three variables that reference an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file

I have a function that reads a txt file and then creates three variables from a combination of `charAt()` values for each line that it reads. The variables are k, k1, and k2. These variables reference a very long array file `myarray[k][k1][k2]` and then writes the value of these array elements to a `div`.

I may be reading up to 400 lines of text and each time the k, k1, and k2 values are created. How would I go about determining if these same k, k1, and k2 values are being duplicated?"

Update - I tried using

```
if ( !(myArray[k] && myArray[k][k1] && myArray[k][k1][k2]))
```

but it did not work, probably because I did not explain my problem properly.

For example, after reading, say line 15, I get values of `k=0, k1=3, k2=10` and these are the values that will be used for `myArray[k][k1][k2]`

These same values, i.e. `k=0, k1=3, k2=10` may not occur again, or they may occur after reading, say line 222 and if this is the case, I want to write something different, i.e. I don't want to output the value of `myArray[0][3][10]` again.
I hope this makes sense.

I think it is best if I include code:

```
    <script src="AllTransit.js"></script>


<script>

var myplanets = 
["SUN    ", "MOON   ", "MERCURY", "VENUS  ", "MARS   ", "JUPITER", "SATURN ", "URANUS ", "NEPTUNE",     "PLUTO  "]

var myplanets1 = 
["SUN    ", "MOON   ", "MERCURY", "VENUS  ", "MARS   ", "JUPITER", "SATURN ", "URANUS   ", "NEPTUNE",   "PLUTO  ", "MC     ", "ASC    "]

var myaspects = ["conjunct", "sextile ", "square  ", "trine   ", "opposite"]

var numval =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var numval1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var numval2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

var r, tplanet, aspect, nplanet, range, k, k1, k2



function loadFile(){

  var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

  var filename = "emmy_test1.txt"
  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  var transits = document.getElementById("transits");

  f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading);


  while (!f.AtEndOfStream){
    r = f.ReadLine();

    tplanet  =  r.charAt(2) + r.charAt(3) + r.charAt(4) + r.charAt(5) + r.charAt(6) + r.charAt(7) + r.charAt    (8)

    for (var j = 0; j < myplanets.length; j++) {
      if (tplanet==myplanets[j]) {k = numval[j]}
    }

    aspect = r.charAt(34) + r.charAt(35) + r.charAt(36) + r.charAt(37) + r.charAt(38) + r.charAt(39) +  r.charAt(40) + r.charAt(41)

    for (var j = 0; j < myaspects.length; j++) {
      if (aspect==myaspects[j]) {k1 = numval1[j]}
    }

    nplanet = r.charAt(45) + r.charAt(46) + r.charAt(47) + r.charAt(48) + r.charAt(49) + r.charAt(50) +     r.charAt(51)

    for (var j = 0; j < myplanets1.length; j++) {
      if (nplanet==myplanets1[j]) {k2 = numval2[j]}
    }

    range = r.charAt(66) + r.charAt(67) + r.charAt(68) + r.charAt(69) + r.charAt(70) + r.charAt(71) +   r.charAt(72) +  r.charAt(73) + r.charAt(74) + r.charAt(75) + r.charAt(76) + r.charAt(77) + r.charAt(78) + r.charAt(79) + r.charAt(80)   + r.charAt(81) + r.charAt(82) + r.charAt(83) + r.charAt(84) + r.charAt(85)

    transits.innerHTML += "<b>" + range + "</b><br>" + myArray[k][k1][k2] + "<br>"
    transits.innerHTML += "<br>"

  }

}

</script>
```

TIA

Comment: Just check whether `myArray[k][k1][k2]` has already been assigned a value?

Comment: To put it into use `if ( !(myArray[k] && myArray[k][k1] && myArray[k][k1][k2]))`. This will evaluate all three. If they are not all set this will return true.

Comment: Have you considered `r.substr` instead of `r.charAt` concats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with undefined variables which can not have properties, i.e.

```
var myArray;
if(myArray[1]) ... // error
myArray = [];
if(myArray[1]) ... // ok
```

So this should work:

```
var myArray = [];

function add(k,k1,k2) {
  if(myArray[k]===undefined) myArray[k] = [];
  if(myArray[k][k1]===undefined) myArray[k][k1] = [];
  if(myArray[k][k1][k2]===undefined) {
    myArray[k][k1][k2] = true; // or anything but undefined
    transits.innerHTML+= k+","+k1+","+k2+"<br>";  
  }
  else {
    // duplicate
  }
}
```

Comment: Jan - That didn't work for me - so I have added my code.

Comment: Ah, I see - I rephrased my answer to suit your code.